# How to fix this "invalid syntax" error in the code while assigning variable a user input?

Tags: python, variables, syntax

On line 3, the variable named `temp_unit` is not seen as a variable and is showing invalid syntax.

```
temp = int(input("what is the Temperature?:")
temp_unit = input("Celcius or Farenheit?:")
if temp_unit == "C" or temp_unit=="c":
    print("The given temperature in Fahrenheit is "+(9/5)*(temp+32))
else:
    print("The given temperature in Celcius is "+(5/9)*(temp-32))
```

Comment: You are missing an ending parentheses at the end of your first line

Comment: What do you mean by "variable named `temp_unit` is not seen as a variable"?

Comment: I guess the assignment to temp_unit doesn't work because of the syntax error (missing close bracket) in the first line.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add parenthesis so it should be this:

```
temp=int(input("what is the Temperature?:"))
temp_unit= input("Celcius or Farenheit?:")
if temp_unit == "C" or temp_unit=="c":
    print("The given temperature in Fahrenheit is "+(9/5)*(temp+32))
else:
    print("The given temperature in Celcius is "+(5/9)*(temp-32))
```

Comment: Questions like this should be closed as typos, not answered.

Comment: There will still be a `TypeError` due to attempted concat of `str` and `float` in the `print` statements